# How to set optional cascade peristance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have set cascade persist in my Entity for OneToOne relation and it works well until I leave field nullable. Is possible to allow leave the field blank?

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\Campaign\TaskPrize", mappedBy="task", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $prize;
```

Error:

> {"code":500,"message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO campaign_task_prize (type, url, disposable, shipping_by_post, created_at, updated_at, task_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, 0, 0, \"2017-07-13 12:26:21\", \"2017-07-13 12:26:21\", null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'type' cannot be null"}

Comment: [`it works well until I leave field nullable`] what is the error here?

Comment: Error indicating missing parameters for the child

Comment: Can you please show us the exception message in your question?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: As I wrote, I'd like to leave prize empty. In this case insertion of campaign_task_prize wouldn't have to execute.

Comment: The cascade persist is triggered if there is at least one instance of `TaskPrize` assigned to `prize` property, so I recommend you check out this part instead of make optional the cascade persist (which is not possible now with Doctrine).

Comment: I found out solution – my FormType sets object.
>->add('prize', CampaignTaskPrizeType::class)

Comment: Could you posted this part of your form type?